# GLUT display window stretching out of window box and duplicating pixels

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glut, freeglut

I've created a simple GLUT program that should simply draw a triangle:

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void render(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
    glEnd();
    cout << "ran" << endl;
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void update(int value) {
    static_cast<void>(value);
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(16, update, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("window");
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}
```

...but it has unexpected results:

[image: screenshot]

When I don't have the update function, it seems to only show the weird screen once and then it fixes itself. It also shows the correct display when dragging the window around. I think it may be an issue with my machine?  I've been able to use OpenGL and GLUT before in the past.

Comment: Can't repro on Windows 10 with FreeGLUT [`v3.4.0`](https://github.com/freeglut/freeglut/releases/tag/v3.4.0).  Which OS, windowing system, and FreeGLUT version are you using?

Comment: @genpfault I am using WSL on VsCode using a Windows 10 computer.  I'm unsure how to tell my version of freeGlut.

Comment: @genpfault I was able to find out the version was 2.8.1-6 but it says this is the latest version of freeGlut.

Comment: WSL1 or WSL2?  Which X server are you using?  Or is this under [the recent WSLg stuff](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg)?

Comment: @genpfault It is WSL2. Not sure what the X server is but I looked it up online and I put in this command: ps -e | grep tty, and I got the out put of:  6261 hvc0     00:00:00 agetty
   6271 tty1     00:00:00 agetty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact issue, same visuals, same environment. I feel silly for not trying earlier, but `wsl --update` and then a restart fixed this for me.